# Accessing video content from a website

Tags: java, python

I need to download lecture videos from [mediasite.com](http://events.mediasite.com/Mediasite/Play/90ab469c653c47808872b517e97737821d?catalog=8f468b66-5de5-4501-b797-f995ad814340). Using this [guide](http://cyberkingrkt.blogspot.com/2009/11/download-video-from-mediasite-server.html), I have been able to do so by saving the site locally and then getting the video url from the "manifest.js" file. However, since this method is long and convoluted, I would like to just be able to script the whole thing.

What tools do I need to complete these three steps:

1. Go to the lecture site
2. Extract video url from manifest.js file
3. Download the video

I've been told that using cURL or the .net lib in java might do the trick but I honestly don't know where to start. Would appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Firebug + Fiddler2 to find direct links.